# Why Americans like to enroll in military services despite huge risks involved?

Tags: united-states, military, war, contemporary-history

Working in US military is one of the riskiest jobs in America because of the regular engagement in battles compared to other military in the world.

I live in a third-world country. Even in my country, military services are considered last resorts for job-seekers.

Being one of the sensible and educated societies in the world, why Americans enroll in Military services?

I know, military services in the USA provide huge salary and benefits, but, isn't being alive more important?

Comment: The short answer is that the USA is *not* one of the most educated societies in the world, and most draftees *are* choosing it as a last resort—for the healthcare and education benefits that they can't get otherwise.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The US is one of the most educated societies in the world, but punches far below its weight among wealthy nations. Also, I think you meant to say *enlistees*, as there has not been a draft in decades.

Comment: This seems awfully close to a question asked before: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/1539/what-incentives-are-in-place-for-american-soldiers-to-go-fight-in-iraq

Comment: @MichaelF, the question that you linked is in no way closer to mine. The differences in the intents of the questions are clearly visible. Are you searching for an excuse to close my question like the wolf who killed the lamb?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "differences in the intents"? Other than the other question explicitly mentioning Iraq (which IMHO makes its phrasing inferior to yours), I don't see a big difference. They both at their heart seem to be asking, "Why would somebody *volunteer* to go fight for the USA in a warzone?"

Comment: This is not really a question of history, but one of contemporary culture and national psychology.

Comment: @T.E.D.: "Being one of the sensible and educated societies in the world, why Americans enroll in Military services?" - was the main question. Whatever. If you want to close it, close it. I don't care. I have got my answer anyway.

Comment: @BROY I was looking for nothing than noting another source of answers you can look at, within the past decade anyone enrolling in the US military WOULD have had to look at risks in Iraq and Afghanistan.  Which in many ways already answers your question

Comment: The basic premise of this question is incorrect.  While serving in an active warzone is dangerous, if you consider all military personnel, fishing and logging are far more dangerous.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many techniques used by military recruiters. You can find a [list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-recruitment#Arguments_surrounding_recruitment). To sum up:

- There are a lot of very poor people in the USA too. As in your county the people recruited don't have better options. This is called "poverty draft" in [many](http://sojo.net/magazine/2007/06/poverty-draft) [articles](http://www.democracynow.org/2004/12/23/a_new_poverty_draft_military_contractors).
- Recruiters give you hope that they will pay for your education
- A recruiter interviewed in the documentary Why We Fight notes that people in his profession have "the bad reputation of used car salesmen." Military defenders argue that the bad actions of a few shouldn't taint the whole. Counter-recruiters argue that high pressure on recruiters creates systemic dishonesty. The U.S. Army shut down its entire recruitment apparatus for a single day in 2005 in order to "refocus" on ethical conduct.
- Recruiters often suggest that personal and technical skills learned in the military will improve later employment prospects in civilian life, with very similar skills utilized for nursing and electronic and mechanical repair.
- The military inaccurately promotes a "romanticized" view of combat - using catchphrases such as honor, courage, and service - and glosses over death, injury, and civilian suffering, in order to give recruits a "soft" vision of the job.

Comment: Take a look at the armed forces' slogans: The few. The proud. The Marines. *(Marines)* ; [Army Strong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slogans_of_the_United_States_Army) *(Army)* ; Accelerate your life *(Navy)* ; [No one comes close](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Air_Force#Slogans_and_creeds) *(Air Force)* ; Semper Paratus (Latin for "always ready") *(Coast Guard)* .

Answer (score 12):

According to [this paper](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1000&context=psc_working_papers) from Penn's Population Studies Center, perhaps to go somewhere safer?

> But it is not difficult to find conditions equivalent to combat in
>   American cities. In Philadelphia, the death rate for black males aged
>   20-34 in 2002 was 4.37/1000, 11% higher than for troops in Iraq. A
>   slight majority of the deaths were from homicide (Philadelphia
>   Department of Public Health, n.d.)

Comment: Well at least some people are better off in the military.

Answer (score 0):

America is a country born in revolution and come of age in civil war.

Basically, it was a country that was "settled" by people who liked to fight, and who were "troublemakers" in their home country. Which is why an embryonic nation could wage a war against its mother country and win. This was true not only of the original settlers, but of most of the people that followed. Their heirs inherited their genes, and probably a number of "traditions" that sprung from that way of thinking.

There is a great gap between rich and poor in the United States. Poor people (African-Americans in inner cities, poor whites in the countryside) live in areas where there is a lot of "gang-fighting" or "brawling." For such people to serve in the military is for them to get (relatively) good pay to live a life like the one they are used to.

Many of these poor Americans are willing to "go for broke" to get rich. This do-or-die mentality was the motto of the 442nd (Japanese-American) Regimental Combat Team of Senator Daniel K. Inouye. The military (and the wild west) is in a sense, an expression of the American way of life.

As for risks, probably Patrick Henry spoke (in 1775) for many (later) Americans when he shouted: "Give me liberty or give me death."

There was a Roman saying, "dulcet et decorum est pro patria morir." (It is a sweet and beautiful thing to die for one's country.) On the surface, it seems like a form of patriotism, but is real meaning may be, "the Roman standard of living so much higher than every one else's that I'd rather be a dead Roman than say, a live (and probably enslaved) Carthaginian." As members of the richest and most powerful country in the world,  Americans often feel that way.

As for Australians (to answer questions in the comments), the ethos is quite similar. The continent was initially settled by "convicts," people who liked to wield arms almost by definition. This ethos is exemplified in the following Australian song: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wild_Colonial_Boy

It's about a robber who would rather fight at the odds of one to three than to surrender (and be hanged). He gets to shoot one of the cops in exchange for his own life. Modern Australians (like modern Americans) are the descendants of such people (the survivors, that is).

Comment: Can we say the same thing about Australia? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convicts_in_Australia

Comment: @VitalijZadneprovskij: Possibly, but probably to a lesser extent.

Comment: This smacks of ahistorical exceptionalism. How do the vast sea of post-Revolution immigrants fit into that story? Or African Americans, who are disproportionately represented in the Army?

Comment: @VitalijZadneprovskij: Australia as a country possesses a very similar attitude as the USA. For example, their policy of handling indigenous people and immigrants are very similar. As to say about foreign policy, they are one of the most active allies of USA in Afghanistan and also participated in Iraq.

Comment: @TomAu, I think this is slightly wrong. If anything, the US had one of the most legal and "happy" revolutions ever. In fact, you could say that China is a bloodier place since the Boxer rebellion, Taiping rebellion, Civil war...were all bloodier than Americans wars. To combat you quotes, I quote Mao Zi Dong: "A revolution is not the same as inviting people to dinner...A revolution is an act of violence by which one class overthroughs another. But, China is not a blood thirsty place, nether is America. Anything can be stated and backed up with rationalization, but rationalization is a fallacy.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Most later immigrants had their own grudges; Irish immigrants against England, Polish immigrants against Russia, German immigrants against most other European countries. As for African-Americans joining the Armed Forces in disprortionate numbers, it's one place where they are likely to be promoted on their merits.

Comment: @TomAu Exactly. This answer is too simplistic since it's ignores the larger, more complicated context.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: My point was that America was populated by people who had "grudges" of one sort or another; both the original settlers, and later immigrants. They passed on such genes to descendants that are more inclined to fight than descendants of people that didn't have such grudges.

Comment: The account of Australian history here is about 80 years out of date.  ( http://members.optushome.com.au/spainter/Dumbing.html )

Comment: @SamuelRussell: The argument is that today's Australians inherited the GENES of people who are "about 80 years out of date."

Comment: …yeah nah, genetic racialism hasn't ever had a place in Australian historiography.  "Britishness" and the "convict stain" and the "convict larrikin" have always been constructed culturally.  So has "Irish"ness for that matter as the racial other.  The idea that a unique cultural contribution to Australian identity came from convict transportation has been pretty much abandoned, in favour of early administrative conflicts and the early conflict over free settlement and status.